# How to point custom domain from Gandi to Google Cloud Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, custom-domain

I'm new to Google Cloud Engine. I have a web app running on GCE and a custom domain in Gandi. I've followed some instruction and add my domain to custom domain.

[image]

But my domain still unverified. I' ve tried to add DNS records but nothing happened.

[image]

Please give me more advise about this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home gives several ways to verify: via domain name provider, TXT record, or CNAME record. Both the direct method and the CNAME method worked for me for verifying the domain from Gandi (aside: I'm still having problem with SSL using Gandi & GAE though)